# Can i inser a list in a single document on MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

In my Python code, i have a list that looks like this:

```
mylist = [ [158, 175], [9347, 38], [8457, 930], [499, 4958] .... ]
```

I'm fairly new to MongoDB, and i would like to find a way to have this array in a single document, but i don't know how to do it.

I tried to insert like this:

```
dic = {"list" mylist}

result = db.mycol.insert_one(dic)
```

It works, but i don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it. Is there a way to store it in a more convenient way? Keep in mind that i don't want to have one document for each element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct if you want to store the `Array` in a single document. And if you want to reset you can use `$set` operator to add/replace elements.